# Can I connect standard Dell displays to a Thunderbolt iMac?

Tags: display

Can I connect standard Dell monitors to a Thunderbolt iMac?
I think the Dell monitors are VGA with DVI-D ports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you get a [Mini-DisplayPort/Thunderbolt to DVI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ), then yes you can hook any DVI display up to your Mac.

Comment: Check out Monoprice for a shaper alternative.